# Serve static files in development with Vite, alias and Vue 3

Tags: asp.net, .net, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to serve static files like images from Vue components and make it work both in development and production, using alias in `vite.config.ts`. Folder structure looks like this:

```
--src
--wwwroot
```

Where `src` is the Vue app and `wwwroot` is where I serve static files in a .NET project.

In a Vue sample project, a typical path looks like this:

```
<img src="@/gfx/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
```

Related `Vite config`:

```
return defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL(isDevelopment ? "./" : "./wwwroot", import.meta.url)),
    }
  },
  base: isDevelopment ? "/" : "/dist/",
  build: {
    outDir: "wwwroot/dist/",
    rollupOptions: {
      input: "./src/main.ts",
    }
  },
  root: "./",
  publicDir: "public",
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1000,
    stictPort: true,
  }
});
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
compilerOptions: {
  "include": ["src/shims-vue.d.ts", "src/env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "src/**/*.ts","src/**/*.js"],
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./src/*"],
  },
  "allowJs": true,
  //...
}
```

With this config, production build will be correct. However development build, no matter what I do, will have wrong urls for static content.

For instance, a path might look like this: `/@fs/assets/gfx/logo.svg` (when @ is an alias for ./) or even worse using alias mapping to ".", "/" or anything else I try.

How can I make this work in both dev and production?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `vite.config.ts` is located? Seem like it is located in the root folder that is the parent of the `src` folder. So the alias should be `isDevelopment ? "./src" : "./wwwroot" `

Comment: Thanks! 

`Vite.config.ts` is indeed located in the path above src and wwwroot. I've tried changing alias to ./src but then static files must be served from Vue app's src location instead of wwwroot, and that means we need to resolve static files path everywhere in the app. The url will be localhost/src/gfx/logo.svg but the Vue app is located in localhost:8000. I think serving from wwwroot is the best really?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's too late to answer but well. I'm not sure how you're structuring your project but keep this in mind:

When the Vite dev server is started. Public assets (from `public` folder) are served on dev server host (ex: `http://localhost:1000`). So your public assets can be accessed with that (ex: `http://localhost:1000/myphoto.png`).
If your scripts or Vue application is running on **ASP.NET** (ex: `https://localhost:8000`) and you tell your scripts or rendered HTML to find "@gfx/logo.svg" or "./gfx/logo.svg". Then it will search on `https://localhost:8000/gfx/logo.svg`, not in `http://localhost:1000/gfx/logo.svg`. You can fix this by creating a middleware that proxies the requests to **Vite Dev Server**.

I have [a project](https://github.com/Eptagone/Vite.AspNetCore) for that. You can install the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vite.AspNetCore/) or just copy the files. Do what works best for you.